# Getting user roles programmatically in Oracle SOA Suite 11g

Tags: oracle11g, soa, roles, oracle-adf

Someone knows how to get a user's roles in a Oracle SOA 11g BPMN application from a backing bean in a TaskFlow??

I need to know the role of the user in order to activate some fields, my idea is to get it from the backing bean and do something. is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options :
EL :

```
#{securityContext.userInRole}
```

But not sure if checking users is what you need.
You can get a hold of the actual role list

```
oracle.adf.share.security.identitymanagement.UserProfile = ADFContext.getCurrent().getSecurityContext().getUserProfile();
```

You can also use groovy in the VO/EO layer, but talking about SOA, I'm not sure if thats really applicable to you...

Comment: Yes, that solved this question for an ADF app without BPM. Unfortunately I found that my problem was that the BPM doesn't sends the authentication info to the human task, so when you use this code the UserProfile is empty, and the ADFContext.getCurrent().getSecurityContext().getUserName() is anonymous. Because of that I asked this question witout results:  stackoverflow.com/q/3259840/194789